# Opening front camera programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I'm working on android marshmallow. In my application I'm trying to open android mobile  front camera pro grammatically for capturing users profile pic & to display it for preview I've tried lot of examples available that're available in the internet none of the app given perfect out put every example is showing loading of back camera on button click.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare this is the URL link I followed [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html )

Answer (score 0):

You can access Front camera by

```
Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
```

and here is the example method you can use to access it

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
int cameraCount = 0;
Camera cam = null;
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        try {
            cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}

return cam;
}
```